# how to find location with business name?

Tags: ios, google-maps, geocoding, core-location, mapkit

I am trying to build an iphone app that finds the location with business name.
For example, I want to annotate a restaurant and I want to find it with the name of restaurant. I was trying to use CLGeocoder, but it seems like geocoder does not help in this case. I am not sure what to do.. can anyone give me a hint about this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Business name" is info independent of the address and not available to `CLGeocoder`. For this you have to use an external service where business names are actually registered. I would suggest the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches), but the search results will still be limited to those businesses registered to Google.

And yes, you will have to dirty your hands with "`NSURL` stuff", and process the results with "`NSJSONSerialization` stuff".

Comment: I see.. Thank you very much!! Oh.. by the way, do you recommend any good tutorials for this? sorry for asking this kind of things, but I am very new to ios programming..

Comment: Browse through [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials). They have easy to understand tutorials. Look for the one titled "How to Translate Text with Google Translate and JSON on the iPhone" as it shows how to process results from a web service.

Answer (score 1):

Google maps will take a business name and return location(s).  It sounds like a webservice is what you're needing, you'll just have to think through the inputs, the outputs, and figure out how it all logically fits into your app.

Comment: hmm.. do i need to use nsurl request stuff??

Comment: I'm not too sure.  I've used python and grep to scrape data manually off of pages, normally that's frowned upon though because there’s typically a public web service or API that can be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to consider an `SDK-based solution`, Huq Industries offer exactly this as part of their [Real-world Analytics](http://huq.io/product.html) platform.  They've done a lot to address the problem of reliably relating `device location` to physical businesses accurately by combining `location` with other data including `WiFi`.  You can get business events by `business name`, `category` and `address`.

Coverage is pretty global and it's mostly free.  Check out the [SDK repo on GitHub](https://github.com/huq-industries/sourcekit-ios).

---

***Disclaimer***: I contributed to this.